# Mono HttpResponse.TransmitFile sending corrupt data

Tags: asp.net, mono

I'm having some trouble with HttpResponse.TransmitFile under Mono/linux.  This code works:

```
using (var f = System.IO.File.Open(FileName, System.IO.FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    f.CopyTo(response.OutputStream);
}
```

Where as this doesn't: (although it does on Windows)

```
response.TransmitFile(FileName);
```

Although in both cases I get back some data, the difference is extreme.  Here's the start of the data as it should be:

```
8950 4e47 0d0a 1a0a 0000 000d 4948 4452
0000 04b0 0000 00a0 0806 0000 001c b895
4700 0000 0473 4249 5408 0808 087c 0864
8800 0000 0970 4859 7300 001b af00 001b
af01 5e1a 911c 0000 0019 7445 5874 536f
6674 7761 7265 0077 7777 2e69 6e6b 7363
6170 652e 6f72 679b ee3c 1a00 0020 0049
4441 5478 9cec bd79 7454 c799 37fc bbbd
492d b5f6 7d97 90d8 1108 3060 b3d8 98dd
3660 6ce2 78c1 d8ce 624f 66be 64f2 bd99
9ce4 cb99 c9c9 36f1 c439 4eec c964 9cc5
9937 f19b 38c9 6499 378e 63c7 3678 5f00
6302 189b cd6c 0281 d086 d46a f5be dcef
0f51 5777 a9ba b76e 770b 845d bf73 38b4
... (109270 bytes total)
```

but this is what I get:

```
3161 6164 360d 0a89 504e 470d 0a1a 0a00
0000 0d49 4844 5200 0004 b000 0000 a008
0600 0000 1cb8 9547 0000 0004 7342 4954
0808 0808 7c08 6488 0000 0009 7048 5973
0000 1baf 0000 1baf 015e 1a91 1c00 0000
1974 4558 7453 6f66 7477 6172 6500 7777
772e 696e 6b73 6361 7065 2e6f 7267 9bee
3c1a 0000 2000 4944 4154 789c ecbd 7974
54c7 9937 fcbb bd49 2db5 f67d 9790 d811
0830 60b3 d898 dd36 606c e278 c1d8 ce62
4f66 be64 f2bd 999c e4cb 99c9 c936 f1c4
394e ecc9 649c c599 37f1 9b38 c964 9937
8e63 c736 785f 0063 0218 9bcd 6c02 81d0
86d4 6af5 bedc ef0f 5157 77a9 bab7 6e77
... (109286 bytes total)
```

It looks like some sort of encoding issue, but I'm stumped as to what it could be or how to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

It starts with `3161 6164 360d 0a`, which is a hex number (`0x1aad6` or `109270` in decimal, which is the is the size of your file) followed by a CRLF.  Looks like chunked encoding to me.

Your HTTP Headers should also contain `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`.

That's nothing to worry about, the server will get the correct data.

Comment: Ah, well spotted.  Not sure what you mean by nothing to worry about, it's supposed to be a PNG file but it doesn't display because it's got that header embedded at the front of it.  The http headers do have chunked encoding set.  The hex dump above is from a downloaded file.

Comment: How are you downloading the file?  The server-side seems to be correct, but it's possible that whatever you're using to download it does not understand chunked encoding.

Comment: Google Chrome.  No it's definitely server related - looking at it in Wireshark, that length prefix is itself prefixed by a length, causing it to become part of the content data.